# UITableview cells "leak" beyond top and botom of Of the Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mac-catalyst

I have several UITableViews in an app and when scrolling, all seem to display one cell above or below the frame of the tableview before the cell disappears.  Any way to have it the disappear or fade as it "departs" before "leaking" past the edge?

Before scrolling
[image]

While scrolling

[image]

code in the custom view controller.   Using Cartography for Layout

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    model = appDelegate.model as CCModel
   
    setupTable()
    createTableContent()
    appDelegate.chordIndex = createSectionIndex()
    appDelegate.leftPanel!.addSubview(appDelegate.chordIndex!)
    appDelegate.chordIndex!.alpha = 0.0
    
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(HoverGestureRecognizer(target: appDelegate, action: #selector(appDelegate.viewHovering(_:)), id: .selectChord))
    #else
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(LongPressGestureRecognizer(target: appDelegate, action: #selector(appDelegate.onLongTip(_:)), type: .selectChord))
    #endif

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
    
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

func setupTable() {
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.tableView!.accessibilityIdentifier = "ChordTV"
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseID)
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    self.tableView.alpha = 0.0 // initially hidden
}

func createTableContent() {
    // create the ChordFamily Dictionary
    CHORDTYPE.forEach { item in
        let out = sChordTableItem(name: item.name, chordTones: item.chordTones, family:item.family, selected: false)
        if (!familyDict.keys.contains(out.family)) {
            familyDict[out.family] = [out]
        } else {
            familyDict[out.family]!.append(out)
        }
        if out.family == "SIMPLE" {
            numSimpleChords += 1
        }
    }
    
    var sectionPointer = 0
    for (index,family) in families.enumerated() {
        familyOffsets[index] = sectionPointer
        sectionPointer += familyDict[family]!.count
        items.append(contentsOf: familyDict[family]!)
    }
    items = items.compactMap {$0}  // flatten ordered list
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let device = Device.current
    let parentSize = self.view.superview!.frame.size
    var widthFraction = CGFloat(0.0)
    if device.isPad {
        widthFraction = 0.4
    } else {
        widthFraction = 0.3
    }
    
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 36
    group = Cartography.constrain(self.view, appDelegate.chordIndex!, appDelegate.chordscaleLabel!, appDelegate.chordIndexLabel!,   replace: group)
    { tv,  index, label, ciLabel in
        
        
        label.leading == label.superview!.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leading + parentSize.width * model.scaleChordFraction
        label.height == 32
        label.trailing == label.superview!.trailing - 10
        label.top == label.superview!.safeAreaLayoutGuide.top + model.labelOffset
        
        tv.top == tv.superview!.safeAreaLayoutGuide.top + 50
        tv.bottom == tv.superview!.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottom - 50
        tv.width == parentSize.width * widthFraction
        tv.leading == label.leading
        
        index.top == tv.top
        index.leading == tv.trailing + model.chordIndexOffset
        index.width == parentSize.width * 0.13
        index.bottom == tv.bottom

        
        ciLabel.leading == index.leading
        ciLabel.height == 32
        ciLabel.trailing == ciLabel.superview!.trailing - 10
        ciLabel.top == ciLabel.superview!.safeAreaLayoutGuide.top + model.labelOffset
    }
    delay(0.1) {
        self.adjustButtons()
    }
    self.view.addShadowToView(image: true)
}
```

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of what you mean? Table do intentionally fetch items off-screen (so they load in more smoothly during scrolling) and render items behind vibrancy effects like toolbars on macOS. I'm not sure if that's what you're referring to, or something else.

Comment: Seed edited version

Comment: Does the Xcode debug view hierarchy works in MacCatalyst? If yes, what does it say before/after scrolls?

Comment: The issue shows up both in the MacCatalyst version and a pure (iPhone) iOS version.   Before the scroll, all table cells are within the frame of the tableview.   After the scroll, there is a table cell outside (above) the table view.

Comment: What happens if you override `safeAreaInsets` to return `.zero` in your table view controller class?

Comment: Used this method, but did not fix it.  https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-ignore-safe-area-insets-in-uikit/